# Is std::complex stored in an interleaved fashion?

Tags: c++, casting, reinterpret-cast

That is, on disk, if I have an array of `std::complex`, is it stored `RIRIRIRI` or `RRRRIIII` or something else?

My real question is - if I have a structure that I have defined that contains two numbers, can I do a reinterpret cast an array of my structure to use functions that would expect a `std::complex` array?

What about memcpy? If both of my structures are floats, that should be ok if they are stored the same?

Comment: You probably want to have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020076/passing-a-c-complex-array-to-c/5020146#5020146

Comment: The answers to my similar question may be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060879/reinterpret-cast-for-almost-pod-data-is-layout-compatibility-enough

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A C++ class is little more than a `struct` with some adornments.  As such, the members defined in a class are arranged sequentially in memory, contiguously for each element of that type.  In other words, an array of `std::complex`, where each element contains `RI`, will be stored `RIRIRIRI`.

You can probably get away with a `reinterpret_cast`, but you will be depending on the `std::complex` implementation if you do so -- and that will probably be just fine.

Comment: I think you meant `RRRRIIII`. All the parts of the real number occur before all the parts of the imaginary number. That being said, relying on this in any way may result in code that doesn't work on some platforms or with some compilers.

Comment: No, `RRRRIIII` is the wrong answer.  Within one `std::complex`, the real number occurs before the imaginary number.  There aren't any "parts" of numbers.

Comment: @Heath Hunnicutt: Oh! Oops, I missed the word 'array' in the OP.

Comment: ;)  By the way, we are neighbors on the openhatch.org map.

Comment: @Heath Hunnicutt: So we are. I wonder where that site gets its data.

Comment: @Omnifarious: I am not sure about yours, but, in my case, it got the data from me typing in my address.

Answer (score 3):

An array of std::complex defined like so:

std::complex array[COUNT];

...is guaranteed to be stored in memory as RIRIRIRI for the reason that array[i] is by definition the same as i[array], which is to say *(array+i). If the array were stored as RRRRIIII there would be no way to point at an individual array element with a simple pointer.

However there is one case in a typical modern PC where this array IS stored as RRRRIIII: after it is copied to a StructuredBuffer for a GPU in Direct3D 11+. The API call that copies the RIRIRIRI array to the GPU may silently rearrange it as RRRRIIII if this improves GPU performance, which in practice it does.

Answer (score 1):

This completely depends on how you stored these in the file in the first place.

You could have done:

```
ofstream file("somefile.txt");

file << complex_var.real() << "\t" << complex_var.imag() << "\n";
```

Or

```
file << complex_var << "\n";
```

The latter will store it (in text form) as ´(realpart,imaginarypart)`. If writing in binary mode, I wouldn't know, but simply trying and see what output is generated would be an  easy (and most likely standardized, in this case) way of seeing what happens.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the physical meaning of an array of a class on disk is. You shouldn't be just writing the bytes to disk, but using real serialization. Then you know the representation yourself.

As for your other questions, don't do that, even if it appears to work (which it might for now). Just create the `std::complex` objects from pairs out of your array and process those objects.