# How to efficiently extract real/imaginary parts of complex matrix in Eigen3 library?

Tags: c++, matlab, eigen3

I have some complex, dense vectors/matrices in the Eigen3 library, and I want to extract the real and imaginary parts into separate arrays. In Matlab, I could do something like

```
cplxFoo = [1, 1i; -1i -1]
re = real(cplxFoo)
im = imag(cplxFoo)
```

which expectantly yields

```
cplxFoo =
   1.0000 + 0.0000i   0.0000 + 1.0000i
   0.0000 - 1.0000i  -1.0000 + 0.0000i
re =
     1     0
     0    -1
im =
     0     1
    -1     0
```

Is there anything like the `real()` and `imag()` Matlab functions in Eigen3?

Right now, the only thing I *know* will work is something akin to

```
MatrixXcd cplxFoo = ...;
MatrixXd re(cplxFoo.rows(), cplxFoo.cols());
MatrixXd im(cplxFoo.rows(), cplxFoo.cols());

for(size_t j=0; j<cplxFoo.cols(); ++j) {
    for(size_t i=0; i<cplxFoo.rows(); ++i) {
        re(i, j) = cplxFoo(i,j).real();
        im(i, j) = cplxFoo(i,j).imag();
    }
}
```

It works, and I can put it in a function even, but then I'm stuck having to do my own loop vectorizing, unrolling, etc., and I have to make an extra copy.

What I would like to be able to do is wrap a couple of `Map<MatrixXd>` with appropriate strides around `cplxFoo` to get the real and imaginary parts. But the problem is that the elements of `MatrixXcd` are `std::complex<double>`, and I'm not sure what the layout of that is. My *guess* is that `std::complex<T>` is essentially laid out like `struct {T real; T imag;};` so that real and imaginary parts are tightly packed and interleaved when you make an array of `std::complex<T>` (and that also seems to be the consensus at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5317777/is-stdcomplex-stored-in-an-interleaved-fashion)), but is that guaranteed by the C++ standard? AFAICT, a compliant C++ compiler could lay it out like `struct {T imag; T real;};` (note the changed order), or something more exotic like

```
class {
    T radius;
    T angle;

public:
    T real() const { return radius * cos(angle); }
    T imag() const { return radius * sin(angle); }
    /* ... */
};
```

So, is it ok to wrap a couple of `Map<MatrixXd>` with appropriate strides around `cplxFoo`? If so, how do I set up the strides correctly?

Alternatively, is there any way to get Eigen's complex data types to use separate chunks of memory for the real and imaginary parts?

For what it's worth, the reason I need to do this is because I need to interface the Eigen library with MATLAB which can only handle separate arrays for real and imaginary parts, not interleaved in any way.

Comment: The layout of `std::complex<T>` is guaranteed to be compatible with an array of two `T` values (real followed by imaginary parts), and for arrays to generalise as you'd expect. (But I don't know enough about Eigen to answer the other questions).

Comment: If I don't get the docs wrong `cplxFoo.imag()` and `cplxFoo.real()` should work. Have you tried that?

Comment: @anderas Hot damn, it works! I wish I would have seen it in the docs, could have saved me a ton of trouble.

Comment: @anderas The combination of your comment combined with Mike's fully answers my question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That's easy, just use the `.real()` and `.imag()` views:

```
MatrixXcd M;
MatrixXd r, i;
r = M.real();
i = M.imag();
```

Note that you can use `M.real()` into an expression without copying it into a `MatrixXd`.

Comment: Is there a way to do the exact same thing but for an Eigen tensor?